# Tomcat trying to open xml files when Spring MVC project run on Eclipse

Tags: xml, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, http-status-code-404

When I run this from eclipse I get a 404 the requested resource() is not available and in the address bar i have `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/web.xml` or `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/springMVCTest-servlet.xml`. Why is it trying to open the xml files?

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the springMVCTest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="/"></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

This is the controller

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;



@Controller
public class SpringMVCTest {

    @RequestMapping({"/","/home"})
    public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("name", "Jess");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd cast a shadow on this:
**You are right-clicking on your `xml` files and choosing RUN**

There is no other way it tries to open `xml` file. Am I right?
**UPDATED**
Add these to your `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> <!-- Your index page -->
</welcome-file-list>
```

And then run again.

Comment: no i'm just clicking on the run icon an then choosing to run on a server.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I included the files above.

Comment: Right-Click on your project name, and select `properties`. See if the `web project settings` is fine.

Comment: It has the context root as SpringMVCTest.

Comment: Updated the answer, check this as well and let me know the result

Comment: 404 with this in the address bar http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: There is something missing here. The `welcome-file-list` forces tomcat to open those pages, when you run the project. Do you have `index.jsp`?

Comment: I placed a copy of home.jsp in the web content dir and it opens fine.

Comment: Does this mean there's no way to prevent the xml files from being attempted to be opened without forcing tomcat to open a welcome file?

Comment: I cannot say that. `xml` files are for configuration and there should be no access to them. In fact I think as you didn't clarify `welcome-file`, this problem occurred. Any web application should have it.